# XUI redirects to /realms/root/users/undefined

Tags: openam

LDAP module is configured as the auth module.

I can see in logs that authentication is successful, but XUI redirects to a URL like this

/openam/json/realms/root/users/undefined

and gives 403. When I try with admin user using CURL command it gives 200OK. Why is XUI getting username as undefined?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWbNF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Which OpenAM version / fork is being used?

`undefined` is returned as the value for the user search attribute configured for the user data stored. You need to check your identity data and the configuration of the user data store. Setting debug level to `message` and inspecting `IdRepo` debug log will help you investigating this issue.